# can we generate different bundlejs files referring to our directories while moving to production in Angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack

I m creating a project in angular 2 where we do have different folder for every component. That all folders are in app directory. So while moving to production, angular is automatically bundling all the components into one bundlejs file. some 4 js files are created. 
1. inline.bundle
2. main.bundle
3. polyfills.bundle
4.vendor.bundle

directory Structure is..

```
--app
     --aboutUs
     --Core
     --Component1
     --Component2
```

So what I want is to create segregated bundled js files for every directory in app folder.
Is it possible.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you just want to lazy load some part of your app: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#lazy-load

Comment: Yeah, this question sounds like it might be suffering from the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you give us the context of *why* you want to split the bundles (which isn't generally a great idea unless you know what you're doing, as it increases the number of HTTP requests your app has to make!), people might be able to give you a better solution.